# How to fix the Heroku failed to push some refs error?

Tags: node.js, git, heroku

I keep getting the failed to push error when trying to push my project to heroku. I followed a couple other answered questions saying to create a new file and push it before connecting to the master, but it still doesn't work for me.

What else can I do to fix this?

[image of the error following me creating a text file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJR7g.png)

Comment: For future reference, you should copy and paste the text into a code block instead of including an image.  Images aren't searchable and they aren't accessible.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you're trying to push the branch `master`, but that branch doesn't exist.  The branch you're on is `masterbranch`, as seen by the output of your root commit.

If you want to push this branch to the remote, you can use `git push origin masterbranch`.  If you want to push it to the remote `master` branch, then you can use `git remote push masterbranch:master`.  If you want to rename it, you can use `git branch -m master` and then push it.

Comment: In the tutorial in the heroku documentation page, it says to need to push the master specifically. How am I supposed to push something that does exist? https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#deploy-the-app


doing the commit master branch command gives me a much different return

Comment: You can push the existing `masterbranch` to `master` using the `git remote push masterbranch:master` command as specified above, or you can rename it to `master` and then push it with `git push origin master`, or you can create a new branch and then push it the same way.

Comment: Doing the 'git remote push' command instantly gives me an error saying that I can't do that claiming `push is an unknown subcommand`

Answer (score 0):

If you pushed your project source code into GitHub, after you deployed to Heroku, branch will be changed from `master` to `main`, so to fix it, type following commands:

1. `git add .`
2. `git commit -am "changes made"`
3. `git push heroku main`

Instead of `git push heroku master`, if branch was changed from `master` to `main`.